# PHP class to know what method has been called inside that class

Tags: php, oop

assuming we have a class

```
class foo{

}
```

and it has no methods
but somewhere in the code , some genius developer called the class and used it like this :

```
$x = new foo();
$x->run();
```

we have no method "run" in our class , but is there anyway that this foo class can know that some code called the method "run" ?

Comment: the code calling this method will raise an error, then you will know where it occured. apart from that, what's the point of having a class with no methods whatsoever?

Comment: Upvoted. Though it could have included more information, the question itself is valid and, judging by the answers, even useful.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can give the class a [magic method named `__call`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php#object.call) that is called when a non existent method is called:

```
class foo{
  function __call($method, $params) {
    echo "Non extisent method $method is called";
  }

}
```

Comment: Wow great ! if i had a private property `private $engine = '';` and in the foo constructor `$this->engine = new otherClass();` how can i `$this->engine->{$method}($params)` ? from within the `__call` ?

Comment: @Ronan: You might want to try something pretty much exactly like what you just typed.  :)  That, or `call_user_func_array(array($this->engine, $method), $params);` if you want the params passed separately.

Comment: @cHao. Almost. :) {edit} Exactly that. :)

Comment: @cHao i need to finish alot of code in order to try and do it , i think ill just write a test code , but am so lazy he :p i hope this theory works ;)

Comment: @Ronan no offense but whatever you are doing it there: you are doing it wrong. [You are not supposed to instantiate objects in the constructor](http://misko.hevery.com/code-reviewers-guide/flaw-constructor-does-real-work/). It makes testing hard. Apart from that, a class with no methods has no responsibility and should not exist.

Comment: @Gordon. It's not empty. Apparently, this class has at least a constructor and a property. And although the Foo class in the question is empty that doesn't mean the real classes also contain no methods at all. :)

Comment: @GolezTrol OP said "assume we have a class and it has no methods". If that is the setup, something is clearly wrong with the OP's code.

Comment: hmmm , guys the foo class has like 6 methods , but some clients asked for custom things in their accounts , so i either had to change half of the system to be able to include and use more calsses (that differs from the foo class in 1-2 methods only , or i could make little classes as additions for the foo class which is what i am doing now without the need to change alot in the system

Comment: and the declaration in the constructor was just to make things clear of what `$engine` is :)

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure what you are looking for is the [__call()](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php) magic method. It is defined as:

**__call() is triggered when invoking inaccessible methods in an object context.**

At this point you can handle dynamic handling of the call.

```
class Dog
{
    function __call($method, $params)
    {
        echo("Sorry, this dog cant " . $method);
    }
}

$bulldog = new Dog();
$bulldog->run();
```

Outputs:
**Sorry, this dog cant run**

Answer (score 1):

It can be achieved with [set_error_handler](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.set-error-handler.php) I think